# UNIX time in decimals in C

Tags: c

How can I get UNIX time in decimals in C, like Python does that?

What I have in C using http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/221083-how-show-unix-time-c

```
me@laptop$ ./time 
1299556464
```

What I want and it works in Python:

```
>>> time.time()
1299556249.3973091
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's open source, it's easy to find out what Python's doing.

From [`Python/Modules/timemodule.c`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Ak5Im_pHmac/Modules/timemodule.c),

```
static double
floattime(void)
{
    /* There are three ways to get the time:
      (1) gettimeofday() -- resolution in microseconds
      (2) ftime() -- resolution in milliseconds
      (3) time() -- resolution in seconds
```

There is also the POSIX function [`clock_gettime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_gettime.html) which has resolution in nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval tv;

gettimeofday(&tv, 0);

printf("%d.%06d", (int)tv.tv_sec, (int)tv.tv_usec);  // Corrected -> to . (it's late!)
```

Officially, POSIX 2008 has deprecated `gettimeofday()`, but it is likely to be around for the foreseeable future.  The casts are safe enough for the next quarter century or so; after that, there could be problems with 32-bit `int` types.  The second argument is strictly a null pointer; the compiler will take care of that coercion.  Any non-null value for the pointer has an implementation defined meaning.  The function always returns 0; there is no virtue in testing its return value.

Comment: @G25: the error means you have dot where you need arrow or vice versa.  My mistake - it's late!

Comment: I would cast to `long`, since by 2038 `long` will definitely be at least 64 bits everywhere, and `long` seems to be the "standard" type implementations use for `time_t` anyway (so the cast will almost surely be a no-op).

Comment: @R..: yes, but I need to teach, too.  Just doing using `long` would simply work for the foreseeable future on Unix-ish systems, but there'd still be the problems with Windows 15 still being an LLP64 system so `long` would not work there; I'd have to use `long long`, spelled something weird like `__int64`.

Comment: `long` will work fine until 2038 even if it's 32-bit, and presumably by then Windows will not exist.

Comment: @R..: ye optimist!  And `int` works fine until 2038 too unless you have to target 16-bit hardware; I don't.